# Worksheet_Event: How to Find a Cell That Cell and Offset 1 & 2 Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm testing the Worksheet_Event code below.  It is doing some weird things.  These are basically 3 parts to this code:

```
#1)  Enter "EXPL-" & Target.Value

#2)  Find a cell in Column R with this language:
"Out of Standard (Comment Needed)"
Then, move over one column, and highlight cell.
Then, go over 1 more column form there, and highlight cell.

#3)  Conditional Format for missing values
```

It seems like #1 and #3 work fine, but #2 doesn't highlight cells in Column S or Column T, it highlights the next cell over from the active cell.  The active cell should be in Column R.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'#1)
  If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Target.Column = 1 Then
     If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
       Target.Offset(0, 0).Value = "EXPL-" & Target.Value
     End If
  End If
ErrHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True

'#2)
lRow = Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRows = Range("R19:R" & lRow)
For Each cell In MyRows
On Error Resume Next
    If cell.Value = "Out of Standard (Comment Needed)" Then cell.Address.Select
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
            End With
    If cell.Value = "Out of Standard (Comment Needed)" Then cell.Address.Select
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
            End With
Next

'#3)
lRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRows = Range("B19:B" & lRow)
MyRows.Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=ISBLANK(B19)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

Comment: The code running on the Change event is making changes to the worksheet which, of course, call the change event, resulting in "weird things". The thing to do is to disable events when the code starts running and enable them only after all changes have been done (Application.EnableEvents = True). Apart from that, I recommend the use of the Range object rather than the Selection object, like MyRows.Formatconditions.Add, without any Select action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments regarding your code (too long to put as comment):

You already have:

```
If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
```

So there is little use to use the line below again (otherwise you would exit the sub):

```
If Target.Column = 1 Then
```

In your case try to avoid using `On Error Resume Next` since it will only skip the errors instead of handling them.

There is no need to use `cell.Address.Select`, `Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select` and `Selection`, instead use fully qualified `Range`, and use it's `Offest` and `Resize` properties.

So instead of using the 3 lines below twice:

```
If cell.Value = "Out of Standard (Comment Needed)" Then cell.Address.Select
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
```

You could use:

```
With Cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 2).FormatConditions(1).Interior
```

Comment: Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are trying to do or not. Let me know what you think. So there are several things wrong with this approach but I wanted to just focus on the the two cells you mentioned.

As others have mentioned, I wouldn't use selections. I would use the offset on your reference to the cell variable in the for loop.

Also, you have two if statements that seem to be setting the selection if the R column contains "Out of Standard (Comment Needed)". These two if statements did not encapsulate the cell formatting statement. This means the cell formatting is executed every time regardless of the text in column R (not sure if this was by design or not). I consolidated that down to one if statement that encapsulates the cell formatting.

For example

```
If 1=2 Then Debug.Print("1st")
    Debug.Print("2nd")
```

This is equivalent to

```
If 1=2 Then
    Debug.Print("1st")
End If
Debug.Print("2nd")
```

2nd will always be printed in this statement because the 2nd debug statement is not within the if block. 1st will never be printed because 1 will never equal 2.

```
If 1=2 Then
   Debug.Print("1st")
   Debug.Print("2nd")
End If
```

In this example neither 1st or 2nd will ever be printed because they both fall within the If block and 1 will never equal 2

Finally, I could be wrong here but I noticed that you were using formatconditions. Maybe your conditional formatting was in your sheet and not in the code. It doesn't appear that you had add a conditional format to this range so I removed the formatcondition and just set the interior formatting of the cell.

```
'#2)
lRow = Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRows = Range("R19:R" & lRow)
For Each cell In MyRows
On Error Resume Next
    If cell.Value = "Out of Standard (Comment Needed)" Then
            With cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
            End With

            With cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
            End With
    End If
Next
```